# RegExp to match Quotes inside CSV field values

Tags: javascript, regex, csv

I've been wrestling for the last days to create a regular expression that would match the quotes (if there are any) in the filed values of a CSV file string.

I would want to match only the quotes or at least the whole field value. e.g. : `""`, `"` ,`a "test"` in a CSV string like this:

```
"ID","iManufacturer","iMPartNumber","iSerialNumber","iSimCategory"
"1","""","230-132-111AA"," " ","a "test""
```

The reason is to escape the quotes if they appear inside values so that the CSV file could be correctly parsed.

Without *lookbehinds* in JavaScript I find it hard to find the solution. So far I've come up with this:

```
(?:[^,\r\n\t\f]*)["]+(?:[^,\r\n\t\f]*)["]+(?:[^,\r\n\t\f]*)(?=",|"\s|"\S)
```

It almost matches the strings that I need (it also matches the  start of the value quote) : `"""`, `" "` ,`"a "test"`. It does not match if on the last row, the last value contains quotes.

Any help? Or maybe other way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this regular expression:

```
"((?:[^,"\n]*?"[^,"\n]*?)+)"
```

You can find an in detail explanation [here](http://regex101.com/r/iJ4gT2#pcre).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! It matches the values that contain quotes inside.